# App Development for iOS and Android: Native vs Hybrid

Tags: android, ios, native, hybrid

i need to develop an App for iOS and Android. I can code in obj. C and Java. The app will display data from a MySQL Database and it will use position Data (around you) to display on a Map. This DB will be managed online.

I think native development is the best for this app. But HTML/JS coding is a lot easier for me. So which way would you go to make a professional app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will never reach the richness, smoothness and complexity you can with Native application development using Hybrid HTML application. It simple is not possible. So if you know both code  languages certainly go with the Native option if you want to reach the best result.

If you however limited with time or want a quicker option without going into the nitty gritty staff then Hybrid should be considered.

Just know that Native development would take you much more time.

So for your question if you want to create a proper professional app then go with the Native option.

Comment: Hi @Emil Adz Can you give me any hybrid ui rendering tutorials..

Comment: Hey @SampathKumar, I don't have any, as I don't develop hybrid application.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, design paradigms in android and iOS are vastly different from each other.
The only acceptable exception I have seen to making native apps is game development which has a separate look and feel.

A good way to manage your data between multiple platforms is by creating RESTful web services and having them communicate via JSON. Although I haven't personally implemented JSON in Objective C, I find Gson to be very useful to connecting to a server via Android.

This way your client can be much lighter with native objects and not having to worry about database health and state on the client.