# How can I choose hybrid or native development based on app category?

Tags: ionic-framework, native, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application, hybrid

Out of all these mobile app categories : Education, Life style, Entertainment, Business, Personalization, Tools, Music and Audio, Books & Reference, Travel & Location, Puzzle

Is there a criteria to decide hybrid vs native development based on app category?

Is it mentioned somewhere on the web ?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to look into the structure of the app itself instead of its category.

If you have an app that is really complex Model-wise, it would be interesting to have an hybrid platform. That would make it easy to unify all of the "back-end" code of the app.

On the other hand, if you app is complex in both the Controller/View parts, developing native gives you huge advantages by dealing with native API's built for those specific environments (Android/iOS).

Note: I'm referring to this design pattern:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Also check this answer:
[App Development for iOS and Android: Native vs Hybrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955053/app-development-for-ios-and-android-native-vs-hybrid?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I completely agree with you. But my particular problem is determining which approach would be most suitable for which kind of apps.

Comment: I understand, but I think it falls in what I said. For example, Music, as you said. It has a ton of platform dependent API's and hardware interaction, so I would be counter-productive to make it hybrid.